# How to subset a data frame and apply the same function over and over?

Tags: r, automation

I have a question that seems rather simple but I can't find a solution for it.

I have a data frame with 57 countries and their GDP over 20 years (1140 observations in total). I want to apply the HP Filter from the package mFilter on each country and then save each result as a new variable. Like this:

```
df <- read.csv("QNA_26062015181325399.csv")

usa <- subset(df, Country == "United States", select = c("TIME", "Value") )

usa.filtered <- hpfilter(usa$Value, type = "lambda", freq = 1600))
```

The problem is I need to repeat this procedure for each country. Is there I can automate this process without having to type the same code 57 times?

Comment: you may take into consideration the `plyr` package which is the practical application of the split-apply-combine procedure. [Here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) you can find the paper about that procedure with example of that package.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your data by Country and lapply the function

```
lapply(split(df[,c("TIME", "Value")], df$Country), 
    function(x) hpfilter(x$Value, type = "lambda", freq = 1600)
)
```

Comment: `by` is also a nice combination of `split` + `lapply`

Comment: Is there a way to quickly save each of the newly-generated filtered series as new variable?

Comment: @DPinto You should save them in a list instead of a new variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `plyr` try:

```
library("plyr")
f = function(x) {
    hpfilter(x$Value, type = "lambda", freq = 1600)
}
dlply(df[, c("TIME", "Value", "Country")], .(Country), f)
```

Comment: Note that if the intermediate data.frame isn't stored, there's no point subsetting out TIME, Value and Country.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `plyr` solution:

```
library("plyr")
hpList <- dlply(df, .(Country), function(x) hpfilter(x$Value, type = "lambda", freq = 1600))
```

Alternatively, you could split the data first and then process it:

```
countryData <- dlply(df, .(Country), `[` , j = c("TIME", "Value"))
hpList <- llply(countryData, function(x) hpfilter(x$Value, type = "lambda", freq = 1600))
```